# Function validation using Prismatic/schema in Clojure

Tags: clojure, plumatic-schema

I have a very simple question about using [Prismatic/schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) to validate functions. I have a schema for a map that has a single key, the value of which is a function that takes a `Bar` schema as its single argument and returns anything (used for side effects):

```lisp
(require '[schema.core :as s])

(def Bar {:baz s/Int})
(def Action :???)
(def Foo {:action Action})
```

The question is, how do I define `Action`? I've tried this:

```lisp
(require '[schema.macros :as sm])

(def Action (sm/=> s/Any Bar))
```

This looks promising, but I can't get it to fail validation:

```lisp
(s/explain Action)
;=> (=> Any {:baz Int})

;; This should fail    
(s/validate Foo {:action :anything-goes})
;=> {:action :anything-goes}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I read the [docs](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) and the tests in [core_test](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema/blob/master/test/cljx/schema/core_test.cljx#L508), but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found this: https://github.com/Prismatic/schema/blob/a21cc0113ed497f6410c55d92d9088bd710f0b47/src/cljx/schema/core.cljx#L888

So it would be something like:

```
(def Action (s/make-fn-schema s/Any [[Bar]]))
```

Although, the documentation does say this:

> Currently function schemas are purely descriptive; they validate against any function, regardless of actual input and output types

Comment: OK, that makes perfect sense. Nice to make schemas of them anyway, as descriptive code that may be enforced in the future has a lot of value. Thanks for your careful reading of the code!